# Android App API 7

Tags: android, logcat

Hello all i have an app it works fine on API 8 but i need it to work on API 7 2.1. the app launches but when i click the button on the spalsh screen to go into the app it force closes on me.

I am using the kankan wheel project if that is any help?

Also i go this from LogCat:

```
    11-22 11:36:53.591: D/ddm-heap(3356): Got feature list request
    11-22 11:36:54.071: D/dalvikvm(3356): GC freed 723 objects / 53872 bytes in 247ms
    11-22 11:36:54.461: D/dalvikvm(3356): GC freed 225 objects / 10080 bytes in 55ms
    11-22 11:37:02.881: D/dalvikvm(3356): GC freed 243 objects / 18368 bytes in 62ms
    11-22 11:37:03.121: D/AndroidRuntime(3356): Shutting down VM
    11-22 11:37:03.121: W/dalvikvm(3356): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40026160)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.insult.kp/kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity.onCreate(PasswActivity.java:72)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    11-22 11:37:03.121: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     ... 11 more
    11-22 11:37:03.131: E/SemcCheckin(3356): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
    11-22 11:37:03.141: I/dalvikvm(3356): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    11-22 11:37:03.151: I/dalvikvm(3356): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    11-22 11:37:04.631: D/dalvikvm(3376): GC freed 760 objects / 55296 bytes in 78ms
    11-22 11:37:04.841: D/dalvikvm(3376): GC freed 235 objects / 10552 bytes in 56ms
    11-22 11:37:05.181: D/dalvikvm(3376): GC freed 337 objects / 24144 bytes in 58ms
    11-22 11:37:05.421: D/AndroidRuntime(3376): Shutting down VM
    11-22 11:37:05.421: W/dalvikvm(3376): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40026160)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.insult.kp/kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity.onCreate(PasswActivity.java:72)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    11-22 11:37:05.421: E/AndroidRuntime(3376):     ... 11 more
    11-22 11:37:05.431: E/SemcCheckin(3376): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
    11-22 11:37:05.441: I/dalvikvm(3376): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    11-22 11:37:05.441: I/dalvikvm(3376): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    11-22 11:37:07.311: D/dalvikvm(3383): GC freed 788 objects / 56384 bytes in 147ms
    11-22 11:37:07.561: D/dalvikvm(3383): GC freed 240 objects / 10768 bytes in 54ms
    11-22 11:37:26.111: D/dalvikvm(3436): GC freed 594 objects / 48896 bytes in 236ms
    11-22 11:37:26.451: D/dalvikvm(3436): GC freed 205 objects / 9176 bytes in 55ms
    11-22 11:37:34.391: D/dalvikvm(3436): GC freed 243 objects / 18336 bytes in 127ms
    11-22 11:37:34.791: D/AndroidRuntime(3436): Shutting down VM
    11-22 11:37:34.791: W/dalvikvm(3436): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40026160)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.insult.kp/kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity.onCreate(PasswActivity.java:72)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    11-22 11:37:34.791: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     ... 11 more
    11-22 11:37:34.801: E/SemcCheckin(3436): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
    11-22 11:37:34.811: I/dalvikvm(3436): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    11-22 11:37:34.831: I/dalvikvm(3436): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    11-22 11:37:36.115: I/Process(3436): Sending signal. PID: 3436 SIG: 9
    11-22 11:37:36.341: D/dalvikvm(3458): GC freed 601 objects / 49176 bytes in 89ms
    11-22 11:37:36.601: D/dalvikvm(3458): GC freed 210 objects / 9400 bytes in 66ms
    11-22 11:37:39.991: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3458): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    11-22 11:38:23.861: D/dalvikvm(3545): GC freed 774 objects / 55792 bytes in 515ms
    11-22 11:38:24.071: D/dalvikvm(3545): GC freed 230 objects / 10368 bytes in 57ms
    11-22 11:38:27.491: D/dalvikvm(3545): GC freed 243 objects / 18360 bytes in 60ms
    11-22 11:38:27.731: D/AndroidRuntime(3545): Shutting down VM
    11-22 11:38:27.731: W/dalvikvm(3545): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40026160)
    11-22 11:38:27.731: E/AndroidRuntime(3545): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.insult.kp/kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity.onCreate(PasswActivity.java:72)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    11-22 11:38:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3545):     ... 11 more
    11-22 11:38:27.751: E/SemcCheckin(3545): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
    11-22 11:38:27.761: I/dalvikvm(3545): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    11-22 11:38:27.761: I/dalvikvm(3545): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    11-22 11:38:32.201: D/dalvikvm(3552): GC freed 779 objects / 56024 bytes in 142ms
    11-22 11:38:32.441: D/dalvikvm(3552): GC freed 230 objects / 10368 bytes in 55ms
    11-22 11:41:22.251: D/dalvikvm(3552): GC freed 341 objects / 24264 bytes in 60ms
    11-22 11:41:22.541: D/AndroidRuntime(3552): Shutting down VM
    11-22 11:41:22.541: W/dalvikvm(3552): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40026160)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.insult.kp/kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity.onCreate(PasswActivity.java:72)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    11-22 11:41:22.541: E/AndroidRuntime(3552):     ... 11 more
    11-22 11:41:22.551: E/SemcCheckin(3552): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
    11-22 11:41:22.561: I/dalvikvm(3552): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    11-22 11:41:22.571: I/dalvikvm(3552): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    11-22 11:41:24.612: I/Process(3552): Sending signal. PID: 3552 SIG: 9
    11-22 11:41:24.831: D/dalvikvm(3626): GC freed 579 objects / 48312 bytes in 79ms
    11-22 11:41:25.031: D/dalvikvm(3626): GC freed 205 objects / 9248 bytes in 55ms
    11-22 11:41:34.621: D/dalvikvm(3626): GC freed 313 objects / 22008 bytes in 55ms
    11-22 11:41:35.651: D/dalvikvm(3626): GC freed 119 objects / 7392 bytes in 56ms
    11-22 11:41:36.231: D/dalvikvm(3626): GC freed 86 objects / 6432 bytes in 63ms
    11-22 11:41:36.641: D/dalvikvm(3626): GC freed 77 objects / 6024 bytes in 56ms
    11-22 11:41:37.041: D/dalvikvm(3626): GC freed 77 objects / 6016 bytes in 56ms
    11-22 11:41:38.661: D/dalvikvm(3626): GC freed 182 objects / 17224 bytes in 57ms
    11-22 11:41:38.741: D/AndroidRuntime(3626): Shutting down VM
    11-22 11:41:38.741: W/dalvikvm(3626): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40026160)
    11-22 11:41:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(3626): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.insult.kp/kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity.onCreate(PasswActivity.java:72)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/AndroidRuntime(3626):     ... 11 more
    11-22 11:41:38.751: E/SemcCheckin(3626): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
    11-22 11:41:38.761: I/dalvikvm(3626): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    11-22 11:41:38.771: I/dalvikvm(3626): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    11-22 11:41:41.161: D/dalvikvm(3636): GC freed 601 objects / 49168 bytes in 71ms
    11-22 11:41:41.371: D/dalvikvm(3636): GC freed 205 objects / 9248 bytes in 54ms
    11-22 11:42:06.711: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3636): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    11-22 11:42:14.291: D/dalvikvm(3695): GC freed 748 objects / 54816 bytes in 203ms
    11-22 11:42:14.691: D/dalvikvm(3695): GC freed 220 objects / 9968 bytes in 59ms
    11-22 11:42:16.721: D/dalvikvm(3695): GC freed 243 objects / 18368 bytes in 59ms
    11-22 11:42:17.161: D/AndroidRuntime(3695): Shutting down VM
    11-22 11:42:17.161: W/dalvikvm(3695): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40026160)
    11-22 11:42:17.161: E/AndroidRuntime(3695): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.insult.kp/kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity.onCreate(PasswActivity.java:72)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    11-22 11:42:17.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3695):     ... 11 more
    11-22 11:42:17.181: E/SemcCheckin(3695): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
    11-22 11:42:17.181: I/dalvikvm(3695): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    11-22 11:42:17.191: I/dalvikvm(3695): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    11-22 11:42:21.771: D/dalvikvm(3711): GC freed 750 objects / 54904 bytes in 69ms
    11-22 11:42:21.981: D/dalvikvm(3711): GC freed 220 objects / 9960 bytes in 54ms
    11-22 11:42:43.901: D/dalvikvm(3711): GC freed 341 objects / 24248 bytes in 57ms
    11-22 11:42:44.131: D/AndroidRuntime(3711): Shutting down VM
    11-22 11:42:44.131: W/dalvikvm(3711): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40026160)
    11-22 11:42:44.131: E/AndroidRuntime(3711): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.insult.kp/kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at kankan.wheel.demo.PasswActivity.onCreate(PasswActivity.java:72)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    11-22 11:42:44.141: E/AndroidRuntime(3711):     ... 11 more
    11-22 11:42:44.151: E/SemcCheckin(3711): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
    11-22 11:42:44.161: I/dalvikvm(3711): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    11-22 11:42:44.191: I/dalvikvm(3711): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the API version, please post the relevant code (PasswActivity), and the layout XML.

Comment: App crashes in PasswActivity class, onCreate method, on line 72.

Comment: without more details (i.e. a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem) I don't think this is answerable.

Comment: The length of the logcat output (might) prevent you from adding relevant code to this question. You really need to shorten it, and show us the code that caused it, or this will (probably) be closed very quickly.

Comment: BTW - you can omit the word Android from the title of your questions, it is enough to add the android tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

- you are calling `findViewById()` on the wrong thing, and therefore are getting an `ImageView` when you are expecting something else
- your `R` class is out of sync with the rest of your code, which can be fixed by cleaning your project (Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu, or `ant clean` from the command line)

Comment: your R class is out of sync was what it was i think thankyou!